# Magento 2 add attributes to footer tag

Tags: magento2, attributes, footer

I wish to add 'role="contentinfo"' attribute to footer tag on the frontend. I see the footer is created via container tag in xml.

```
<container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
```

Is there any argument for adding role attribute?

Comment: Can you please specify, what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`role` is not allowed whether in `container` of `block`, otherwise you're going to have a pretty Exception like:

> Element 'container', attribute 'role': The attribute 'role' is not
> allowed.

Allowed **container** attributes:

```
name
label
before
after
as
output
htmlTag
htmlId
htmlClass
```

Allowed **block** attributes:

```
class
display
name
before
after
template
as
cacheable
ifconfig
```

[Magento 2 layout devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html)

Alternative Way, maybe you can do it via jQuery with something like :

`$('#containerId or .class').attr('name', 'value');`